# GCloud App Engine (flexible) Default Service Account Scope

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, app-engine-flexible

I'm trying to connect to a google calendar from service running in GCP App Engine flexible environment using default service account. I have set correct scope required to access the calendar to read only events (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly`) and I'm able to access the calendar locally when impersonating the service account.

My service runs on java spring boot and getting below error

```json
{
  "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "service": "calendar-json.googleapis.com",
      "method": "calendar.v3.Events.List"
    }
  }
}
```

### Code Snippet

```kotlin
val scopes = listOf("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly")
val credentialsProvider = GoogleCredentialsProvider.newBuilder().setScopesToApply(scopes).build()

val calendarService = Calendar.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                                GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                                HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentialsProvider.credentials))
            .setApplicationName(applicationName)
            .build()

calendarService.events().list(config.calendarId)
            .setSingleEvents(true)
            .setTimeMin(DateTime(Date()))
            .setMaxResults(4)
            .execute()
```

**Dependencies**

- com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:3.1.0
- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2021.0.1
- com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter
- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-appengine
- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk
- com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev411-1.25.0

### What I've Tried

I have accessed the metadata endpoint on app instance directly to check provided token. Only to find out the given token has no specified calendar scope.

```sh
$ curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.events.readonly" -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google'
{"access_token":"ya29.xxxxxx....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................","expires_in":3518,"token_type":"Bearer"}

$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "access_token=$token" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo
{
  "issued_to": "xxxxxxx",
  "audience": "xxxxxxx",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.apis",
  "expires_in": 3493,
  "email": "<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "access_type": "online"
}
```

Comment: Remember service accounts only work with google calendar if they were created from your workspace domain account.  Also you need to configure domain wide delegation on it.   Which method are you using your only asking for read only scope.   Its not going to give you access to any of the write methods.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I granted access to service account in the calendar settings. When I execute the code locally with impersonated service account e.g. `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account <project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`, I'm able to read events.

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine instance can have the permissions of the service account limited by **access scopes**.

The scopes that you list are the default access scopes [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam). This means the scopes you add are filtered out by the VM instance settings.

In the Google Cloud Console GUI, change the **Access scopes** for the VM instance to be **Allow full access to all Cloud APIs**. You can also use the CLI [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes).

Comment: @DaImTo - I am not referring to APIs. I am referring to Access Scopes assigned to the VM instance. When setting up the OAuth Scopes for an attached service account, the Access Scopes can limit which scopes actually get assigned.

Comment: @DaImTo - The VM instance has a feature **Access Scopes**. When the client requests an access token (from the metadata server) with the Calendar scope, if Access Scopes is not set to **Allow full access to all Cloud APIs** the Calendar scope will be ignored when generating the token.

Comment: @DaImTo - I am referring to App Engine Flexible which runs on Compute Engine and not App Engine Standard.

Comment: @DaImTo - My answer does not cover Domain Wide Delegation. I am only answering why the  Calendar Scope is not present in the requested token.

Comment: @DaImTo - The service account assigned to Compute Engine is just like any other service account. Follow the same procedure to set up DWD.

Comment: @DaImTo - If you mean delete these comments, I would leave them. Others might better understand VM Access Scopes.

Comment: I thought I could do something like that, but I guess app engine flexible is not entirely the same as compute engine VM. I'm not able to add access scopes to it via console nor gcloud cli.